# if value of column 3 is greater than cap print it in tmp not working properly

Tags: bash, awk, sh, gawk

```
 awk '$3>$cap{print $0}' $f > $tmp
```

So $f and $tmp are the files through which I iterate. In each files if value of column 3 is larger than cap which varies for each file, that line is printed in tmp(exclusive for each $f) file. It works correctly for some lines but some lines with smaller value also gets printed. Can someone help me on this

Comment: is `cap` a bash variable? If so, try to use `awk -v cap="$cap" '$3>cap{print $0}'`

Comment: Err, $tmp is an output file here if you have a `greater than sign` in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to read `bash` variable using `awk`

```
awk -v var="$cap" '$3>var' "$f" > $tmp
```

or

```
awk '$3>var' var="$cap" "$f" > $tmp
```

Your variable does not expand within singe quote `'code'`
You do not need `print $0`, its the default action of there is no action.
Always double quote variable name "$cap" to make sure no formatting is lost.